# How to Get File security attribute in windows

Tags: c++, windows, security, mfc

I am using c++ MFC

How can I get the file security attribute in windows, is there any handy api?

Many thanks!

Comment: The security attribute on what?

Comment: Copied the word "file" from the title to clarify the question body.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please check

[The Windows Access Control Model Part 1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/accessctrl1.aspx)

[The Windows Access Control Model: Part 2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/accessctrl2.aspx)

Also, take a look here [Windows Access Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374860(VS.85.aspx))

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446639(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

There's no handy C++ API, at least not in MFC. The CFile model supports any kind of file system: NTFS, but also FAT and CDFS (for CD-ROMs). Hence it generalized a lot. NTFS-specific features such as ACL, ADS etcetera are not supported. You'll still need to use the raw Win32 API for that.